# How to compare worst-case time complexity?

Tags: big-o

In the below 4 options, wasn't 3., i.e, O(*n*²) supposed to be the worst time complexity? Because it takes more time to run and log(*n*) takes lesser time to run? But unfortunately the answer given is option 4.

What's wrong with my logic?

1. O(log(*n*!))
2. O(*n*)
3. O(*n*²)
4. O(log(log(*n*)))

Comment: Sounds like you have misunderstood the question, or it is wrong. Option 4 is the "best" time complexity among the listed ones

Comment: If you want an idea of how these functions will behave in the long-term, a nice (quick) way is to plot them on wolframalpha (where you will see `n^2` shoot off much faster). There's also taking the limit of `f(n) / g(n)` (where `f` and `g` are two functions you're comparing), as well as just direct math (e.g. `n^2 > n` because dividing by `n` gives you `n > 1` which is definitely true as `n` grows infinitely).

Comment: Presumably you have confused *worst* with *worst-case*. So this is rather an English-language question than a math/computer science question.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the direct question, this is the order of the functions from *best* to *worst*, sorted by their *worst-case* time-complexities (what we would call big-O notation):

1. O(log(log(n))
2. O(n)
3. O(log(n!))
4. O(n^2)

This is pretty easy to see in a graphing of the functions:
[image: Plotting input to output]

(Note that `O(log(log(n)))` is nearly a constant function, an iterated logarithm. Thus it does not stray far from the x-axis).

Big-O notation describes the worst-case time complexity for any function, but the question likely originally asked for the best worst-case time complexity.